# Backup files of a bootable flash drive for future use

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, bootable-media

I want to have a couple of bootable flash drives (such as Windows Recovery Drives) without having multiple *physical* drives. I thought I'd just copy the files, and later - create a bootable drive using `diskpart`. Unfortunately, when trying to recreate a drive from the files. It failed. (A WD Acronis True Image bootable media.)

I tried both `fat32` and `ntfs` (the original was fat32). The partition ***was*** primary. But it still failed to boot.

Is there an additional step needed when using the files themselves (instead of an `iso` file)?

Answer (score 0):

For having multiple images on a flash drive, I use [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). It's small and works well. It takes an iso file and puts onto the drive. You can simultaneously have as many iso's as you have size for. Yes, it was originally designed for Linux, but I've used it for Windows already and it works just fine.